# subset rows + context

Tags: r, subset

I haven't been able to figure out an easy way to include some context ( n adjacent rows ) around the rows I want to select.
I am more or less trying to mirror the -C option of grep to select some rows of a data.frame.

Ex:

```
a= data.frame(seq(1:100))  
b = c(50, 60, 61)
```

Let's say I want a context of 2 lines around the rows indexed in b; the desired output should be the data frame subset of a with the rows 48,49,50,51,52,58,59,60,61,62,63

Comment: This is very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155609/returning-above-and-below-rows-of-specific-rows-in-r-dataframe/13156365#13156365

Comment: Indeed... let's hope this question will help user end up on the right answer; my searches had not yielded this result..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this, but there may be a more elegant way to compute the indices :

```
a= data.frame(seq(1:100))  
b = c(50, 60, 61)
context <- 2
indices <- as.vector(sapply(b, function(v) {return ((v-context):(v+context))}))
a[indices,]
```

Which gives :

```
 [1] 48 49 50 51 52 58 59 60 61 62 59 60 61 62 63
```

**EDIT :** As @flodel points out, if the indices may overlap you must add the following line :

```
indices <- sort(unique(indices))
```

Comment: @user1317221_G Yes, `c` will do, but without anything `sapply` returns a matrix.

Comment: @flodel Yes, you're right, I've edited my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.