# Creating a column that repeats adjacent values in R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a column `y` that mirrors the value of another column `x` and sets the adjacent values to the non-NAs.

Let's say I've got a data.frame `df`:

```
df = data.frame('index' = 1:10, 'x' = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA))

> df
   index  x
1      1 NA
2      2 NA
3      3  1
4      4 NA
5      5 NA
6      6 NA
7      7  2
8      8 NA
9      9 NA
10    10 NA
```

Now I want to create the column `df$y` which forms some 'context' around the non-NAs in `df$x`. Specifically, value of these `df$x` (here: 1 and 2) applies to the their index PLUS one before and one after their index, so that:

```
> df
   index  x  y
1      1 NA NA
2      2 NA  1
3      3  1  1
4      4 NA  1
5      5 NA NA
6      6 NA  2
7      7  2  2
8      8 NA  2
9      9 NA NA
10    10 NA NA
```

I've tried to do this by finding the relevant starting and ending indices of the "context" around the 1 and the 2 with:

```
temp_list = sapply(df$index, function(i){
  if(!is.na(df$x[i])){
      target_index_start = i - 1
      target_index_end = i + 1
    mini_context_iter = df$x[target_index_start:target_index_end]
  } else {
    NULL
  }
})
```

... and this returns a nice list. 
The problem is that this does not seem to handle the indices that are outside of the `-1:+1` context. A related question is [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758243/subset-rows-context) but it stops before creating the new column.

Any ideas how I could address this more precisely?

Comment: @stephenHenderson this will give a column of 1s and NAs... but wont give a 2 etc when x==2

Comment: oops sorry the answer is cleaner anyway..

Comment: you need to explain your context. Take few rows from your output table and explain how and why the y column is 1 or 2 or NA

Comment: @user5249203 i dont think you needto understand WHY to be able to give a code for a problem. You only need to understand HOW and that will enable you code it. WHY is a personal reason.

Comment: @Onyambu, good sol. I could not understand the basis of the of `df$y` column. Hence asked for clarification. So, why is not personal it is regarding the df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%mutate(y=coalesce(x,lead(x),lag(x)))
   index  x  y
1      1 NA NA
2      2 NA  1
3      3  1  1
4      4 NA  1
5      5 NA NA
6      6 NA  2
7      7  2  2
8      8 NA  2
9      9 NA NA
10    10 NA NA
```

Comment: that's interesting I hadn't seen `coalesce` before.

Comment: This is awesome. A quick question: how would this look like in a more generalised way where it's not +1 and -1 but, say +2 and -2?

Comment: @ben_aaron. You can rolapply. Or simply do coalesce(x,lead(x),lead(x,2),lag(x),lag(x,2))